# MySql ExecuteReader no trae resultados [C#]

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, sql

buenas, tengo la consulta, estoy con un pequeño proyecto en C#, pero tengo el problema de que una query que al ejecutarla en mysql me trae correctamente los resultados pero cuando se ejecuta en mi codigo, me reconoce que devuelve una fila, pero cuando ejecuto el .read() no me devuelve nada, y si reviso lo que me devuelve, me muestra el siguiente mensaje

> enumeration yielded no results

cabe aclarar que los parametros se pasan correctamente, pero eso simplemente falla, y cuando reviso los parametros no publicos, ahi encuentro el resultset con los valores que buscaba

ColumnasDB y queryes es un archivo de recursos para reemplazar los nombres de las columnas

query usada:

```
Select * FROM usuarios WHERE username = '{0}' AND password = '{1}'
```

el codigo en cuestion es este:

```
string conex = Conn.Connexion();
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conex);
        try
        {
            MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand();
            comando.CommandText = string.Format(queryes.Login, txtUsuario.Text, txtPasswrd.Text);
            comando.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            comando.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            var reader = comando.ExecuteReader();
            var list = new List<UsuarioEntity>();
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {

                    list.Add(new UsuarioEntity
                    {
                        User = (string)reader[ColumnasDB.username],
                        Nombre = (string)reader[ColumnasDB.nombre],
                        Apellido = (string)reader[ColumnasDB.apellido],
                        Matricula = (int)reader[ColumnasDB.matricula],
                        Perfil = (string)reader[ColumnasDB.perfil],
                        Activo = (bool)reader[ColumnasDB.isactive],
                    });
                }
            }

            if (reader.ToString() != string.Empty)
            {
                UsuarioEntity user = new UsuarioEntity();
                user.Nombre = txtUsuario.Text;
                user.Perfil = reader.ToString();

                MessageBox.Show("ConexionAbiertaCorrectamente");
            }

            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
```

version de .Net 4.6

Comment: Podrías indicarnos que cadena se guarda en `comando.CommandText` antes de realizar `ExecuteReader`, lo digo para saber si estas construyendo correctamente la consulta. Además, ¿Que valor devuelve en `reader.HasRows`?

Comment: esto es lo que devuelve, claramente, devuelve lo que necesito, pero como valores privados
https://imgur.com/a/6Esgt
https://imgur.com/a/aA0zS

Answer (score 0):

Deberias usar parametros en tu codigo y no el `string.Format()`, tu codigo deberia lucir como esto

```
try
{
    string conex = Conn.Connexion();
    using(MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conex))
    {
        con.Open();

        string query = "SELECT * FROM Tabla WHERE usuario = ?usuario AND password = ?password";
        MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("?usuario", txtUsuario.Text);
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("?password", txtPasswrd.Text);

        var reader = comando.ExecuteReader();
        var list = new List<UsuarioEntity>();

        while (reader.Read())
        {

            list.Add(new UsuarioEntity
            {
                User = (string)reader[ColumnasDB.username],
                Nombre = (string)reader[ColumnasDB.nombre],
                Apellido = (string)reader[ColumnasDB.apellido],
                Matricula = (int)reader[ColumnasDB.matricula],
                Perfil = (string)reader[ColumnasDB.perfil],
                Activo = (bool)reader[ColumnasDB.isactive],
            });
        }

    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

observaras el uso del `comando.Parameters.AddWithValue()` es alli donde asignas el valor

Ademas no necesitas validar el `HasRows` ya que sino hay registros no ingresara el `while`

El `using` define un scope seguro donde trabajar con la conexion, por lo que no necesitas realizar el close

Comment: pruebo y te confirmo

Comment: lamentablemente, trae el mismo resultado, los valores los trae como privados, no se por que, pero bueno, adjunto captura

https://imgur.com/a/zY2Vm

Comment: estas evaluando que valor signas a los parametros? quizas para ese usuario y password no exista ningun registro. Valida ademas si aplica keysensitive, o sea si diferencia entre mayusculas y minusculas los valores de los parametros

Comment: probe hasta harcodeando la misma quer que uso en mysql, tire el proyecto, y lo volvere a crear de cero en la semana, lamentablemente, fue algo que de un dia para el otro dejo de traer registros

Comment: si ejecutas la consulta simple como ser: "Select * FROM usuarios" tampoco obtienes registros ? o sea no le defines ningun filtro

Comment: no, al final era un problema de unas referencias que me habian quedado que estaban dnado problemas

Comment: que raro, pero ese problema de referencia no genera un exception ? porque deberias haberlo detectado por ese lado y no en la ejecucion de la query

Answer (score 0):

Inténtelo de esta forma:

```
string conex = Conn.Connexion();



 MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conex);
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand();
        comando.CommandText = string.Format(queryes.Login, txtUsuario.Text, txtPasswrd.Text);
        comando.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        comando.Connection = con;
        comando.ExecuteNonQuery();

        var reader = comando.ExecuteReader();
        var list = new List<UsuarioEntity>();
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {

                list.Add(new UsuarioEntity
                {
                    User = reader["AquiVaElNombreColumna"].toString(),
                    Nombre = reader["AquiVaElNombreColumna"].toString(),
                    Apellido = reader["AquiVaElNombreColumna"].toString(),
                    Matricula =Convert.ToInt32(reader["AquiVaElNombreColumna"].toString()),
                    Perfil = reader["AquiVaElNombreColumna"].toString(),
                    Activo =Convert.ToBoolean( reader["AquiVaElNombreColumna"].toString())
                });
            }
        }

        if (reader.ToString() != string.Empty)
        {
            UsuarioEntity user = new UsuarioEntity();
            user.Nombre = txtUsuario.Text;
            user.Perfil = reader.ToString();

            MessageBox.Show("ConexionAbiertaCorrectamente");
        }

        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
```